How to use egit from the command line?
How to use the git command line directly in Eclipse with egit installed ?
Does anyone know? I appreciate it.

You can install the TM Terminal Plugin and use git for from there like in any other command line.

Eclipse egit is just a GUI; the CLI command is git.

Eclipse EGit is the Git integration/support for the Eclipse IDE and based on JGit, a Git implementation in Java, not on the command line Git.
